# Normalized CSS, option in JSFiddle, how to add it to document

Tags: css, normalization

We have had an applet built for us in JSFiddle. It only works though when one ticks the box that says `normalized CSS`. How do we activate that on our website. I have never heard of it.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=normalized#choose-framework

> Next is the Normalized CSS checkbox, selected by default. If selected, the fiddle will be rendered with normalize.css which is removing most of the browser styling of many HTML tags.

You'd want to include the following file in your template/pages.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css
```

I'd recommend copying it and referencing a local copy rather than referencing it on their server though, that's bad form :)

Comment: Just beat me to it! Here is the actual CSS file in question: http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css

Comment: You beat me to that by 2 seconds .. ah, that stings :)

Comment: Well done. I see how it works. I've added it to our stylesheets

Answer (score 4):

What the normalized CSS is on jsfiddle is a `CSS Reset`

To add it on your site, copy in paste the following code: [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)