# List-element "dots" end up outside section element

Tags: html, css

I am creating a `<ul>` and `<li>` wrapped by `<section>` tag. Everything works fine except the list style (dot) display outside of my `<section>` tag. I am not sure why. I appreciate it if someone can share tips. Thanks a lot.

my html

```
<section id='test'>
    <ul>
       <li>line 1 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 2 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 3 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 4 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 5 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 6 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
       <li>line 7 jiofjisojfoisdjfoisjfio</li>
   </ul>

</section>
```

CSS

```
section { 

    display: block;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 3px solid red;

}
```

It displays like this..

```
 ----------------------
*| line 1 jioj..       |
*| line 2 jiof..       |
*| line 3 jiof..       |
*| line 4 jiof..       |
*| line 5 jiof..       |
*| line 6 jiof..       |
 -----------------------
```

The black dot is outside of the section tag.

Comment: what is your browser. chrome shows it fine http://jsfiddle.net/8WQDY/

Comment: I used Chrome too.that's so weird. I use the same code on jsfiddle. it gave me this     http://jsfiddle.net/y8DLg/   but yours shows fine on my screen Rab.

Comment: @FlyingCat You need to uncheck the Normalized CSS checkbox on JSFiddle, at least I missed that at first.

Comment: ok it's shows correctly in jsfiddle but my codes don't show correctly in chrome.

Comment: If you add all your code and CSS in to a fiddle, does it still show properly there?

Comment: Firefox shows correctly but not in IE nor Chrome. soooo weird....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shows it fine [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8WQDY/)

keep unchecked the Normalized CSS checkbox on JSFiddle

Comment: would u care to explain what Normalized css does?

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625454/normalized-css-option-in-jsfiddle-how-to-add-it-to-document) explain the normalized css option.

Comment: that fiddle will be rendered with normalize.css which is removing most of the browser styling of many HTML tags.

Comment: @Rab, thx for the answer, but my problem is still not solved though :(.  +1

Comment: I think it is solved. you need to overwrite browser default style.

Comment: @RabNawaz But isn't it the other way around? On JSFiddle it works when you uncheck Normalized CSS.

Comment: if I could understand it right. then no it is not. your link explains it