# descenders clipped in Firefox input field

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     input {
       /* line-height: 1.6em; */ /* doesn't seem to make any difference */
       height: 1.6em;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="foo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>First Name:</label> <input type="text" value=""/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I place the code in a file in my filesystem or in a JBoss server and I navigate to it, Firefox `57.0.3` does not rendered the text input field tall enough resulting in the descenders of all letters being clipped:

[image]

Chrome renders it just fine.

Curiously, the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wLosq11/1/) is rendered properly from both Chrome and Firefox.

What am I doing wrong and why can't I reproduce this in the jsfiddle?

I would assume that height of even `1em` should be sufficient, let alone `1.6em`.

Comment: just a question : what if you directly use px value ? it works ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it does work for `28px` but I'd rather express it in `em`.

Comment: yes i know :) simply want to see if it's the height not working or only the conversion. So it's seems an issue with the conversion

Comment: @Stijn Firefox `57.0.3` on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

Comment: The fact you can't reproduce it tells us you have CSS applying in your case which is not present here. `em` is relative to font-size. There must be a combination of `font-size`, `line-height` and `padding` producing this. You need to find a way to repro it here if you want proper help. Does using `rem` help? `rem` is dependent on `<body>`s font-size.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I am not sure what you mean `you have CSS applying in your case which is not present here`. I placed the entire html shown above in a file on my file system and directly opened it with Firefox. Do you mean that Firefox' s agent stylesheets come into play? In that case I should also see the problem in jsfiddle. Moreover I have another user reporting the exact same situation from a Mac `10.12.6` running `Firefox 57.0.4`.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. Something applies there and it doesn't apply in the fiddle or here. Otherwise, it would render the same. All browsers, including FF, will consistently produce the same result, given the same conditions. Maybe FF applies different styles on files loaded from the file system. Does viewing your the file through a local web server fix it? Or maybe some resource fails to load in that case. Point being we can only help if it's verifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a combination of the font, and a smaller-than-default `height` value. On my system, the default font size is `13.3333px` and the default (computed) height is `23px`. This is a ratio of ~1.725, which is slightly higher than your `1.6em`.

`1em` height isn't enough, because there is a border and padding involved to draw the input field. See the box model below:

[image: screenshot of box model]

You're not able to reproduce it in jsfiddle due to the CSS normalisation that is [active by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625454/normalized-css-option-in-jsfiddle-how-to-add-it-to-document).

Comment: I need to set it to `2em` to get to render properly in Firefox at which point it's too tall for Chrome. So you're saying that Firefox and Chrome use different default font sizes and default computed heights? Why can't I repro this in jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle has a CSS reset to normalise across browsers, doesn't it? Maybe if you use a CSS reset stylesheet yourself, the issue is resolved.

Comment: Good point about jsfiddle's CSS reset. However `box-sizing: content-box` is the default in CSS so height `1em` should suffice, shouldn't it?

Comment: The default is `border-box`, at least in Firefox 57.

Comment: OK, so explicitly setting the `box-sizing` to `content-box` and reducing the `height` to `1.1em` produces acceptable results in both Chrome and Firefox. Curiously `1em` was still not sufficient, even with `content-box`.